# Undefined thing in my python program

Tags: python

Its an absolutely abhorrent and awful code, and I have no real idea on how to proceed, I'm rather lost here and this undefined variable is only causing immense stress. The finalists variable is an imported list from a CSV, and for some reason it's undefined, an explanation and steps to fix this would be extremely helpful.

```
def finalistsOpen():
    import csv
    with open('Diving championship_Finalists csv file.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        finalists = list(reader)

    print finalists

    return finalists


def scoreCalculator(finalists):
    scores = []
    sortedScores = []
    for number in range(5):
        print ("Please enter a score for " + finalists[number])
        print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        for number in range(5):
            scores.append(validation(0,10))
            maxScore = scores[0]
            minScore = scores[0]
            for number in scores:
                if number > maxScore:
                    maxScore = number
                elif number < minScore:
                    minScore = number
                    scores.remove[minScore]
                    scores.remove[maxScore]
                    sumScore = sum[scores]
                    sortedScores.append(sumScore)
    return sortedScores,sumScore
    print scores
    print sumScore
    print sortedScores

finalistsOpen()
scoreCalculator(finalists)
```

This is the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Computing Assignment 2018\Finalist.py", line 40, in <module>
    scoreCalculator(finalists)
NameError: name 'finalists' is not defined
```

Comment: We can't solve your stress, we can only answer specific questions related to this code.

Comment: So where's the undefined variable?

Comment: finalists is undefined, I have no clue why, it prints out fine

Comment: I wasn't asking you to solve my stress Daniel

Comment: Where is it undefined? The error message includes a line number. And where do you print it and it exists?

Comment: its unidentified when its in def scoreCalculator(finalists), I've updated my code since asking the question, I'll include the error message

Comment: Why are there `print` statements _after_ the `return`?

Comment: Testing the output of the program, didn't keep them there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finalistsOpen()
```

needs to be

```
finalists = finalistsOpen()
```

Comment: `finalists[number]` is a list, and if you want to make it take part in string concatenation, one way is to turn it in to a string: `str(finalists[number])`.

Comment: I decided to remove the +, replacing it with a ,